# REST $filter startswith on contenttypeid fails when 500 item or more

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

I use the following REST query:

http://portal/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyForms')/Items?$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId,%270x010101008801EC40791D47909E988DEB1A1B9EFD006D679758256E403D9B766451FDA53DBF%27)

This query works fine and we use it for quit some time. Our list has now reached 500 items. And now our query doesn't work anymore. When I delete 1 item and we have 499 items in the list the query works again.

I have tried adding $skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&$top=100
But no luck.

Is there a 500 item limit for REST?

### Update during testing

I found an issue with my list. I have an expiration policy on my contenttypes. The expiration policy timer job has set an index on my contenttype field. When I remove this index my query works again with 500 or more items. sadly the index is recreated on contenttype when the expiration policy timer job runs.

### Update after analyzing the ULS

When I do a trace I see that my REST query is translated to the following CAML query:

```
<Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='Text'>0x010101008801EC40791D47909E988DEB1A1B9EFD006D679758256E403D9B766451FDA53DBF</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query>
```

This query fails when I execute this from CSOM.

```
    using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://d-ccp-portal"))
    {
        Web web = ctx.Web;
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Beheerde documenten Forms 2");

        var q = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='Text'>0x010101008801EC40791D47909E988DEB1A1B9EFD006D679758256E403D9B766451FDA53DBF</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>" };
        var r = list.GetItems(q);                ctx.Load(r);                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

r = 0

The problem seems to be the value type. When I replace my CAML query like so:

```
<Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x010101008801EC40791D47909E988DEB1A1B9EFD006D679758256E403D9B766451FDA53DBF</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query>
```

I do get all my items

```
   using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://d-ccp-portal"))
    {
        Web web = ctx.Web;
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Beheerde documenten Forms 2");

        var q2 = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x010101008801EC40791D47909E988DEB1A1B9EFD006D679758256E403D9B766451FDA53DBF</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>" };
        var r2 = list.GetItems(q2);                ctx.Load(r2);                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

So the problem seems to be that REST doesn't set the correct "value type" when you do a $filter on startswith(ContenTypeId)

Why the index on my list also has influence I don't really know. Because when there is no index on contenttype the first query also works fine.

Comment: check the list threshold on central admin

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/105543)

Comment: The threshold is set to 5000 items. I only have around 505 items and the query fails when 500 or more

Comment: Do you have any entries in the recycle bin? Those count with threshold too.

Comment: Empty recycle bin. See my ULS analysis. It looks like wrong CAML is generated and index is causing issue too

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following REST API to achieve it.

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyForms')/Items?$filter=substringof('0x010101008801EC40791D47909E988DEB1A1B9EFD006D679758256E403D9B766451FDA53DBF',ContentTypeId)&$top=5000
```

Comment: When I run this query I get a status 500 error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904) and a SQL exception in the ULS log when there are more then 500 items. When I remove some items ad have 499 this query also works. SQL Error in ULS: Unknown SQL Exception 8116 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  Argument data type sql_variant is invalid for argument 1 of like function.

Comment: I can confirm that running with less than 500 items I get an empty result. With more than 500 I get the SQL exception. When I remove the index on contentype I always get a empty result. Also with more than 500 items

Comment: Try to add $orderby=ContentTypeId desc in REST API. And remove the $filter to check if it works.

Comment: I can do a orderby. But I need to do a $filter. Check my ULS log finding. I think there is a bug when you use contenttypeid. ValueType should be set to ContentTypeId then it would work

Comment: We can also use CAML query with REST API to achieve it. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-rest-api-caml-query

Comment: For our current requirement we have to use a GET request with only URL params.

Comment: As a workaround, we can get all items and filter the data in the results.